# How can I apply a seam position?

Tags: uv-image-editor

Whenever I import an Image texture for this toothpaste tube, the seam appears on the top of the tube, not the side. In Edit Mode I have tried 'Marking a seam' and it shows as a red line, but the image won't rotate to align with it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks[image: See image below]

Comment: You just have to properly UV unwrap the model. 
Here's a tutorial introduction to UV unwrapping in Blender.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM&ab_channel=Blender

Comment: maybe check if you haven't created another UV Map, if not please share your file: pasteall.org/blend

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, of the dozens of UV videos I've watched, your recommendation was one of the best ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image won't move itself depending on where you put seams, it is you who have to edit the 2D unwrapping of your 3D model onto your picture.

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me thinking about the issue in a different way. However, when I define the Seam position and Unwrap, the seam still isn't to left or right of the 2D map, but in the middle, so I still have to cut the map up and move it around before importing my Image texture. I'm sure this is not how it's supposed to work!

Comment: Editing the UVs isn't just setting up seams on your mesh and hitting the unwrap button. You need to go in the UV editor, select your UVs and manually move, rotate and scale bits around so that they do what you need.